# Create a New page in a specific space and update it with existing file Contents in Confluence in python using REST API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, confluence-rest-api

I am writing a Python script to create a new Page on Confluence and update the page with the contents which is in html file.Below is my code.I am using the confluence version 5.8.10

```
import argparse
import getpass
import sys

import json
import keyring
import requests

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Globals

BASE_URL = "https://wiki.hurry.com/rest/api/content"

def pprint(data):
    '''
    Pretty prints json data.
    '''
    print json.dumps(
        data,
        sort_keys = True,
        indent = 4,
        separators = (', ', ' : '))


def write_data(auth, html, title):

    ver = 'TEST'

    data = {
        'type' : 'page',
        'title' : str(title),
        'space' : {'key' : TEST},
        'body'  : {
            'storage' :
            {
                'representation' : 'storage',
                'value' : str(html),
            }
        }
    }

    data = json.dumps(data)

    print data

    url = '{base}/?os_authType=basic'.format(base = BASE_URL)
    print url
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        data = data,
        auth = auth,
        headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
    )

    r.raise_for_status()



def get_login(username = None):
    '''
    Get the password for username out of the keyring.
    '''

    if username is None:
        username = getpass.getuser()

    passwd = keyring.get_password('confluence_script', username)

    if passwd is None:
        passwd = getpass.getpass()
        keyring.set_password('confluence_script', username, passwd)

    return (username, passwd)


def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        "-u",
        "--user",
        default = getpass.getuser(),
        help = "Specify the username to log into Confluence")

    parser.add_argument(
        "-t",
        "--title",
        default = None,
        type = str,
        help = "Specify a new title")

    parser.add_argument(
        "-f",
        "--file",
        default = None,
        type = str,
        help = "Write the contents of FILE to the confluence page")

    parser.add_argument(
        "html",
        type = str,
        default = None,
        nargs = '?',
        help = "Write the immediate html string to confluence page")

    options = parser.parse_args()

    auth = get_login(options.user)

    if options.html is not None and options.file is not None:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Can't specify both a file and immediate html to write to page!")

    if options.html:
        html = options.html

    else:

        with open(options.file, 'r') as fd:
            html = fd.read()

    write_data(auth, html, options.title)


if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
  r.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 928, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://wiki.hurry.com/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic
```

Could someone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems that your url `https://wiki.hurry.com/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic` cannot be posted.

Comment: @Tiny.D I changed this latter but I tried with this one as well https://wiki.hurry.com/rest/api/content and getting the same error.

Comment: It seems that `wiki.hurry.com` is not working at all?

Comment: Getting same error.This is not the actual url.

Comment: are you sure `wiki.hurry.com` can be connect from your side?

Comment: @Tiny.D If I use https://<actual_host_name>/rest/api/content it gives me lots of data

Comment: @Sushant The problem is definitely on your side (judging by `400 Client Error`) but it will be extremely difficult to tell why because we don't know how the request should be properly formatted on client side for the service you are hiding from us :) Either let us know this information or be sure that you are constructing your request properly.

Comment: @errata Yes you are correct it looks the problem is my side I made below small request and it created the page {"body": {"storage": {"representation": "storage", "value": "<p>This is a new page</p>"}}, "space": {"key": "TPT"}, "type": "page", "title": "None"}.I was trying to post the contents of html but I removed that and passed small value and it worked.So I think passing the contents of file doing some mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you got `400 Client Error` the problem is definitely on your side. RESTful APIs usually expect JSON data, not HTML.

Be sure about the data you are sending and the way you are using Requests, because Requests are performing additional stuff "behind the scenes" depending on what you pass to some of the methods (e.g. adding `json` parameter to `post` will automatically append `Content-Type: application/json` header in your request).

Also, be sure you understand [HTTP response codes](https://www.google.is/search?q=http+response+codes&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNjdLy5_DTAhVEUlAKHZ23AJYQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=699#tbm=isch&q=http+response+codes+cats) ;)

Comment: Yeah but one thing is very strange for me when I was using requests.put to publish the contents of same HTML file then it was working but when I am using request.post then it is creating the problem.It seems very strange to me.I have a file releaseNotes.html which is having the storiesname.module and other etc information.

Comment: @Sushant Updated my answer with more details... Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. If you will have further issues, ask a new question, rather than updating this one.